# Average consective nth row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array.

```
x=np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(100,64,1000))
```

I want to average every 4th row, for example first 4, then 4-8, 8-12 and so on.
I tried the following way

```
x =np.split(x,len(x)/4)
np.mean(np.stack(x),1)
```

I am bit confused if its the correct way? Or if there is a better way. Also how to do if first dimension is not completely divisible by 4.
For example, I can do this way

```
x =np.array_split(x,len(x)/4)
np.stack([np.mean(i,0) for i in x],0)
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is my use case.
This is sensor data, where 100 is the number of time data been collected (trials), 64 is the number of channels of sensor and 1000 is sensor signal (length). I want sensor signal to be average for first 4 trials, then next 4 trials and so on.

Comment: The answer is probably `reshape` but your request is not clear. Shall it be done on the serialized array? just on one dimension, if so in which? do you care about the border values?

Comment: I have added information, in question, please check that

Comment: 1000 is number of trials? what would be your expected output shape?

Comment: No, 100 is the number of trials

Comment: so you want 25 averages, 100 = 25*4 ??? what is the final output shape you expect

Comment: the final output shape would be `(25,64,1000)`

Comment: ohk, thanks for the clarification, I have added a solution which should work for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `np.reshape` and `np.mean` for multiples

Try this with a `reshape` and then `mean` over the specific axis -

```
x = np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(100,64,1000))

#Reshape to (4, 25, 65, 1000) and then reduce 0th axis with a mean
x = x.reshape(4,-1,64,1000).mean(0)
x.shape
```

```
(25, 64, 1000)
```

### Using `np.pad`, `np.reshape` and `np.nanmean` for non multiples

Adding this general solution just incase the axis is not a multiple of 4. This starts with padding the numpy array to the next highest multiple of 4 with `np.nan` and then uses reshape as before, followed by `np.nanmean` which ignores nan values for its mean.

```
x = np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(109,64,1000))

n = 4 - x.shape[0]%4     #remainder to next multiple of 4
p = ((0,n),(0,0),(0,0))  #padding config for each axis

x_padded = np.pad(x.astype(float), p, 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)
x_reshaped = x_padded.reshape((4,-1,64,1000))
x_avg = np.nanmean(x_reshaped, 0)
x_avg.shape
```

```
(28, 64, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastes way is probably reshaping the array, then using `mean`.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(100,64,6144))
# the following will crash if shape is not divisible by 4!
temp = x.reshape((4,-1)).mean(axis=0)
# you have to identify for your use case how to re-shape the array after averaging
result = temp.reshape((x.shape[0]//4, x.shape[1], x.shape[2]))
```

You will need to check if the shapes are devisible by 4 and if not make them divisible.

you can also do it in any one dimension:

```
result= x.reshape((100,4,-1,6144)).mean(axis=1)
```

Simply split one dimension into a 4 and a -1 (i.e. the let numpy calculate it by itself) and then average over the dimension where you have your 4 samples.